# Group objects by key order

Tags: javascript

Formulating this problem is a bit complicated so bear with me.

I'm creating a Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) component, the records are given as a list of objects, like below:

```
[
    { "slice_type": "information" },

    /* Question 1 */
    { "slice_type": "question" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },
    { "slice_type": "quote" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },

    /* Question 2 */
    { "slice_type": "question" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },
    { "slice_type": "image" },
    { "slice_type": "youtube_embed" }
    ...
]
```

As you know in a collapsible FAQ, the question is always on the header bloc while the rest of the content lays in the body of the component.

[image: Representation of a collapsible FAQ]

Thus is why I need to group the answers of each questions in a list, I will then be able to fetch the desired answers by the question index, here's what I'd like to get.

```
[
    [
        { "slice_type": "content" },
        { "slice_type": "quote" },
        { "slice_type": "content" },
    ], 
    [
        { "slice_type": "content" },
        { "slice_type": "image" },
        { "slice_type": "youtube_embed" }
    ],
    ...
]
```

I'd like to know how I can achieve this result programatically?

Comment: how are you supposed to know when it starts a question and it ends in the input list??

Comment: Is `slice_type` always one of the values you have listed here? (e.g. "question") or are those placeholders for actual content? (If they are placeholders I don't see any way you can programmatically group those objects, but if they are consistent and each group starts with a "question", it should be do-able)

Comment: @DBS @AlbertoSinigaglia `slice_type` is a fixed value, it will not change, the placeholders have been removed so it's easier to understand.

Comment: Okay, so will every group start with an object containing `"slice_type": "question"`?

Comment: @DBS Yes, this would be the separator to know the start of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce),

You can iterate through the array and for each item check if the `slice_type` property is equals to `"question"`

- if create a new array for that question,
- if not add the object to the array of the previous question.

**Like so:**

```js
let newData = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (obj.slice_type == "question") acc.push([])
  else acc[acc.length - 1]?.push(obj)
  
  return acc
}, [])
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [
    {"slice_type": "dataBeforeQuestion"},

    /* Question 1 */
    { "slice_type": "question" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },
    { "slice_type": "quote" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },

    /* Question 2 */
    { "slice_type": "question" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },
    { "slice_type": "image" },
    { "slice_type": "youtube_embed" }
]

let newData = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (obj.slice_type == "question") acc.push([])
  else acc[acc.length - 1]?.push(obj)
  
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(newData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: @HiroyukiNuri I've made an edit to my post which should fix that, but I'm not sure whether or not you want to include data that isn't in a question, or remove it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, the data before is not part of the FAQ, so it shouldn't be there

Comment: @HiroyukiNuri No problem, I've made another edit to my post now, hopefully this should give you the behaviour your expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with a `forEach()`. Since you might have items before your questions actually start(as shown in sample data) you should start your index with -1.

```js
let items = [
    { "slice_type": "information" },

    /* Question 1 */
    { "slice_type": "question" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },
    { "slice_type": "quote" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },

    /* Question 2 */
    { "slice_type": "question" },
    { "slice_type": "content" },
    { "slice_type": "image" },
    { "slice_type": "youtube_embed" }
  
]

let groupedItems = [];
let quesIndex = -1;
items.forEach((x) => {
   if(x.slice_type == 'question' ){
     groupedItems.push([]);
     quesIndex++;
   }
   else if(quesIndex!=-1){
     groupedItems[quesIndex].push(x);
   }
});

console.log(groupedItems);
```